# Ui button wont move the same amount with different size screens in roblox

Tags: user-interface, menu, roblox

I have a side menu that slides and it has some buttons on it but when i resize the screen (like make the toolbox bigger) it doesnt show all (or none) of the buttons becuse it does not move the same amount to the side

This is the code im using:

```
local opening=false
local open=false
local buttonopen=script.Parent.open
buttonopen.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if opening==false then
        if open==false then
            opening=true
            buttonopen:TweenPosition(script.Parent["mv to"].Position, "Out", "Quad", .5)
            wait(.25)
            buttonopen.ImageLabel.Rotation=180
            wait(.25)
            opening=false
            open=true
        else
            opening=true
            buttonopen:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.005, 0, 0.42, 0), "Out", "Quad", .5)
            wait(.25)
            buttonopen.ImageLabel.Rotation=0
            wait(.25)
            opening=false
            open=false
        end
    end
end)
```

ive tried useing a ui frame (as you can see in the code) called "mv to" and it did not work

Any help?
(this is a edit later i found out its the ui elements not the same pos bc if i make the roblox studio window short it will make it so that if theres 2 buttons one on top of the other with a gap they will touch)